# Pass values between pages using session variable in VB.NET form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I am trying to create session variable for 2 items so I can use it between pages. However the variable will be the search results displayed in the form. In the code behind how can I get the value of the control.

aspx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="txtdate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Inci_date", "{0:d}")%>'></asp:Label>
```

VB.NetCode:

```
Dim strDate As String = ""
If strDate Is Nothing Then
        strDate = DirectCast(frmUpdateIncident.FindControl("txtInciDate"), Label).Text
End If
Session("IncidentDate") = strDate
```

My Varialbe strDate is still empty.

Comment: More explanation and/or more code is needed to help you on this

Comment: Did you notice the name you use to find the label is diff the label's ID?

Comment: Need to see where your code is in reference to a full or partial postback. If a full postback occurs before strDate is set, then it will always be empty or null. But its hard to tell with out see more code.

Comment: @DonA - Thanks for noticing the silly error. I did change that; along with it making the change to "IsNot  Nothing" I am getting the data.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strDate As String = ""
```

This condition is always false, since "" != Nothing, String.IsNullOrEmpty is better suited to test string emptiness conditions.

```
If strDate Is Nothing Then
```

Also in your label, is your label inside a databing control like GridView?
If no then you cannot set your label text with server side tags, you must use code behind `txtDate.Text="abc"`, maybe in Page_Load.

Regards.

Comment: @Joaj Pinho. Thank you.  I changed it to "IsNot Nothing" that made the difference.

Comment: @Nita U're welcome. I prefer String.IsNullOrEmpty although. Also when initializing string to "", consider using String.Empty, it's a constant string that helps you avoid the "" repetition in your code, "" uses memory and every "" uses different places in your programs memory, while String.Empty point to a single place in memory.

Comment: Pinho. I am using VB.NET and I don't see the property of IsNullOrEmpty. Also for declaration, I can see only vbNull. Thanks for the enlightment regarding "" and memory. Am still learning .net

Comment: Pinho - ok I can say this: Dim strDate As String = Nothing and also say: If strDate IsNot Nothing OrElse String.Empty Then. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Nita - oh sorry IsNullOrEmpty is declared in the String class, so you should call it like String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDate). But yes you can call it like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that it is a date not just not empty using IsDate. So

```
Dim strDate As String = ""
If IsDate(txtInciDate.Text) Then
        strDate = txtInciDate.Text
End If
Session("IncidentDate") = strDate
```

Comment: Since the control is inside the form I have to use "DirectCast" to find the control. Thank you.